# ASP.Net WebApi netcore 2.2 access local file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I read somewhere that .NetCore 2.2 has a bug in `GetCurrentDirectory` method. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4206

We have an ASP.Net WebApi with netcore 2.2.

I was wondering, what is the best way to access a local file which is located in my root directory.

There are too many examples but am looking for the best practise that will work locally and on production (docker container).
Currently i use this syntax:

```
var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string csvPath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, fileName);
```

The csv file will be always copied to the output directory and once published it will be in the same folder as the executables.

Other syntax like:
Injecting the `IHostingEnvironment` in the service and then call the `ContentRootPath`. like this:

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

public Service(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
  _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}

string csvPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, fileName);
```

Comment: ContentRootPath works in local and Docker containers

Comment: @Matt.G thanks for your comment. Ok! is this method with injecting IHostingEnvironment a good way, or should it be done in other way?

Comment: I believe this is the only way to get hold of the IHostingEnvironment value

Answer (score 2):

There is one way, that is worked for me with .Net core 2.2.

you can access the file in your .Net application using following line.

```
 string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory),filename);
```

And copy your file inside the docker container while building image.

```
COPY --from=build /app/ .
COPY --from=build /app/[folder-where-file]/ .
```

Comment: It should be `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` as a method call.